# html canvas windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y) implementation

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

In this book [Core HTML5 Canvas: Graphics, Animation, and Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132761610) I found the author implemented **windowToCanvas** as

```
function windowToCanvas(canvas, x, y) {
   var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

   return { x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width  / bbox.width),
            y: y - bbox.top  * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
          };
}
```

But I do think it should return:

```
          { x: (x - bbox.left) * (canvas.width  / bbox.width),
            y: (y - bbox.top)  * (canvas.height / bbox.height)
          };
```

Am I right?

You can freely view the chapter [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=6).In **example 1.6**

Comment: Yes you are right. You could have verified it by scaling your canvas with CSS. Now, this won't make a good answer for SO...

Comment: Thanks, put this question here just for people reading this book  confused by this function.